# Printing an array in a table format

Tags: java, arrays, printf, output

I have an array filled with 50 numbers and cannot figure how to output the array into a table like format.

Currently when I print my array it is being outputted into one long line of numbers, and what I am aiming for is 10 lines, each consisting of 5 numbers.

Furthermore I would prefer each value to be a 3 digit value. So 1 would be represented as 001, to improve readability and presentation.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Random50 {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX_SIZE = 50;
        int[] r50 = new int[MAX_SIZE];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i<r50.length; i++)
        {   
            r50[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);

            for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {               
                if (j!=i && r50[i] == r50[j])
                {
                    System.out.println("Duplicate: " + r50[i]);
                    r50[i] = rand.nextInt(1000);
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(r50));

    }

}
```

Comment: Show an example of what you tried, have a look at [Print an array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661489/print-an-array-elements) (duplicate?) and at [```'0' flag``` in format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

Comment: As an aside- Since the j loop will terminate before j is equal to i, you don't need the `if (j != i)` cehck.

Answer (score 1):

You really should only ask 1 question per post so I'll answer your first question - it makes it so other users can find relevant information in the future (not trying to be mean).

If you want to start printing on a new line every fifth number you could make use of the `modulus` operator `%`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    if(i % 5 == 0){ // True every fifth value
        System.out.print("\n"); // Print a new line
    }

    ... // Your other code goes here
}
```

Comment: you are printing two newlines :)

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm new to here! When i entered the code you gave, instead of making a new line after every 5 values of [i], it instead just creates 5 blank lines first, and then still a row of my 50 numbers.

Comment: @freshwaterjoe The `for loop` in my post is just an example.  You need to put the `if` statement from my answer inside of your `for loop`.  I believe that would be `for (int i=0; i<r50.length; i++)` for you.